# Skip tests in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I've set up a build on Jenkins for a Maven project, and I would like to build it without running any of the tests.  I've tried entering "clean install -DskipTests" in the goals field, like this:

[image]

But it doesn't work.  What am I doing incorrectly?

*Note:  I want to skip the tests without touching the pom.  I have a separate build that DOES run the tests.*

Comment: the maven goals you are specifying are just fine... just don't specify the `test` goal and you should be golden.

Comment: @sircapsalot I'm confused... how am I specifying the `test` goal in the above example?  Or are you saying I'm specifying it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm saying, as long as you *dont* put the `test` goal, it shouldn't run the test.  If you just specify `clean install` it's running the tests?  if so, could you post the pom?

Comment: @sircapsalot: Nope, if you run _install_, it will also run all lifecycles prior to install - including test.

Comment: I solved it.  I actually needed to enter `clean install -DskipTests=true`.  I had omitted the `=true`.

Comment: The solution given here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303178/maven-not-skipping-tests-with-skipteststrue-skiptests

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is that I omitted `=true`.  I was able to build without running tests by entering:

```
clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: Could you provide the versions of your maven-surefire-plugin and also jenkins? For my latest LTS version and with surefire 2.17, "-DskipTests" works just fine. It would be interesting to find out why this happens.

Answer (score 14):

Just to extend the answer, maven has 2 options for skipping tests:

`-DskipTests=true`  — The one that was mentioned. With this parameter, maven ignores tests completely.

`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` — With this option maven compiles the tests but doesn't launch them.

So you may want to use the second option instead as fast code compile validation. E.G.: if you develop some library or module that will be used by some one else you must be sure that you don't brake contract with the client. Tests compilation can help you with this.

Use either of these parameters depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @iMysak, that's actually really useful info that I didn't know before.  :)

Answer (score 3):

use "Goals and options" value is "clean install -DskipTests=true".

it works like a Charm. I saved hours of time using this Option. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use option "-DskipTests=true" in "Invoke top-level Maven target" -> "JVM Options" and it works fine.