# Exclude testng tests while building in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, testng

I have a test which consists of both junit test and testng tests. It works fine when i run 'mvn test' from parent pom, but testng tests fail while building in jenkins. I need a way to skip testng tests from running in jenkins.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/22514502/2646526.

Comment: Check why your test fails in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You said you use jenkins so i assume that you are using maven plugin :

Have you tried to skip test cases in your Maven run? Use the code below in maven properties section of maven plugin:

```
 maven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Or

please use below code in properties section of maven plugin to skip the test cases

```
skipTests=true
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set it up via runtime in Jenkins' job configuration:

Invoke Top Level Maven -> Advanced.
Add maven.test.skip=true

Once the tests are OK, just remove this line.

You can disable test execution in runtime as well:
    mvn  -Dmaven.test.skip=true