# maven not skipping tests with <skipTests>true</skipTests>

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

if I run maven on the command line:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

this actually works and it skips the tests, but if I do it in eclipse, it still always runs the tests

```
<plugins>
       <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/UTest*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>                                    <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass/mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So I tried three different ways, all shown above:

```
1) <skipTests>true</skipTests>
2) <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
3) <excludes>...</excludes>
```

Within eclipse it will always run the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly plugin does not run the tests. Maven Works through lifecycle phases. The `install` phase will trigger (not exhaustive) compiler-plugin, surefire, failsafe, assembly.

More information here, [What are Maven goals and phases and what is their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-are-maven-goals-and-phases-and-what-is-their-difference)

The surefire plugin handles the running of unit tests, to completely skip tests you can add the following to your plugins configuration

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Failsafe is an Integration Test runner.

Comment: If you look above, I have that and it still runs tests (in eclipse)

Comment: No you don't. You are configuring the Assembly plugin in your example.

Comment: That did it. I will have to read that link yo provided a bit more indepth - thanks!